# How to insert scrollbar in a specific position in Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

Hi guys i'm having trouble with a scrollbar, in the photo you can see the grey box that is a simple listbox, how to put the scrollbar in that red specific position, and not in the right or bottom end of the screen just like te normal scollbar? Thanks!

adding code:

```
from tkinter import *
from ctypes import windll
def inserisci_spesa():
    global lista_spese
    global testo_nuova_spesa
    if testo_nuova_spesa.get() != "":
        lista_spese.insert(0,testo_nuova_spesa.get())
def invio_aggiungi_spesa(e):
    window.bind("<Return>",illumina_aggiungi_spesa)
def illumina_aggiungi_spesa(e):
    bottone_inserisci_spesa.config(bg="#052b4d")
    window.after(200,illumina_aggiungi_spesa2)
def illumina_aggiungi_spesa2():
    bottone_inserisci_spesa.config(bg="#1e476b")
    window.after(0,inserisci_spesa)
def invio_descrivi_spesa(e):
    window.bind("<Return>",illumina_descrivi_spesa)
def illumina_descrivi_spesa(e):
    global bottone_inserisci_descrizione
    bottone_inserisci_descrizione.config(bg="#052b4d")
    window.after(200,illumina_descrivi_spesa2)
def illumina_descrivi_spesa2():
    global bottone_inserisci_descrizione
    bottone_inserisci_descrizione.config(bg="#1e476b")
windll.shcore.SetProcessDpiAwareness(1)
window = Tk()
frame = Frame  (window)
frame.pack(padx=150, pady=150)
window.geometry("1500x770")
window.title ("Gestione spese")
window.call('wm', 'iconphoto', window._w, PhotoImage(file="trasparente.png"))
sfondo = PhotoImage(file="soldi.png")
etichetta_sfondo = Label(window,image=sfondo)
etichetta_sfondo.place(x=0,y=0)
testo_nuova_spesa = Entry(window,borderwidth=5,font=("Ink Free",20),width=9,bg="#f2f2f2")
testo_nuova_spesa.place(x=36,y=80)
testo_nuova_spesa.bind("<FocusIn>",invio_aggiungi_spesa)
descrizione_testo_nuova_spesa = Label(window,text="Nuova spesa",bg="#64d981",font=("Ink Free",19),relief="solid",borderwidth=1)
descrizione_testo_nuova_spesa.place(x=40,y=28)
testo_descrivi_spesa = Entry(window,borderwidth=5,font=("Ink Free",20),width=22,bg="#f2f2f2")
testo_descrivi_spesa.place(x=300,y=80)
testo_descrivi_spesa.bind("<FocusIn>",invio_descrivi_spesa)
descrizione_testo_descrivi_spesa = Label(window,text="Descrizione",bg="#64d981",font=("Ink Free",19),relief="solid",borderwidth=1)
descrizione_testo_descrivi_spesa.place(x=304.5,y=28)
bottone_inserisci_spesa = Button(window,text="Inserisci",font=("Ink Free",15),bg="#1e476b",fg="white",activebackground="#052b4d",activeforeground="white",command=inserisci_spesa)
bottone_inserisci_spesa.place(x=36,y=140)
bottone_inserisci_descrizione = Button(window,text="Inserisci",font=("Ink Free",15),bg="#1e476b",fg="white",activebackground="#052b4d",activeforeground="white")
bottone_inserisci_descrizione.place(x=300,y=140)
lista_spese = Listbox(frame)
lista_spese.pack(side=LEFT)
lista_spese.configure(font=('Courier 20 '), width=21, height=9, bg="#4a4a4a", fg="#dedede",relief="solid",borderwidth=4)
etichetta_lista_spese = Label(window,text="Lista delle spese",bg="#64d981",font=("Ink Free",19),relief="solid",borderwidth=1)
etichetta_lista_spese.place(x=720,y=270)
scrollbar = Scrollbar(frame,command=lista_spese.yview)
scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT,fill=Y)
lista_spese.config(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
window.mainloop()
```

[image]

Comment: put both (`Listbox` and `Scrollbar`) in the same `Frame`

Answer (score 1):

Simply put both (`Listbox` and `Scrollbar`) in the same `Frame` to group them.

---

Minimal working code

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root['bg'] = '#ff8080'

# - create -

frame = tk.Frame(root)
frame.pack(padx=150, pady=150)

listbox = tk.Listbox(frame)
listbox.pack(side='left', fill='both', expand=True)

scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(frame, orient='vertical', command=listbox.yview)
scrollbar.pack(side='right', fill='y')
#scrollbar.pack(side='left', fill='y')  # `left` also works

listbox.config(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)

# - add some values to listbox for scrolling -

for i in range(50):
    listbox.insert('end', str(i))

# - start -

root.mainloop()
```

Result:

[image]

---

**EDIT:**

You may also use `Frame` to create own widget `ScrolledListbox` and then you can reuse it many times.

```
import tkinter as tk

class ScrolledListbox(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.listbox = tk.Listbox(self)
        self.listbox.pack(side='left', fill='both', expand=True)

        self.scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(self, orient='vertical', command=self.listbox.yview)
        self.scrollbar.pack(side='right', fill='y')
        #self.scrollbar.pack(side='left', fill='y')  # `left` also works

        self.listbox.config(yscrollcommand=self.scrollbar.set)

# - main -

root = tk.Tk()
root['bg'] = '#ff8080'

# - create -

lb1 = ScrolledListbox(root)
lb1.pack(side='left', fill='both', expand=True, padx=25, pady=25)

lb2 = ScrolledListbox(root)
lb2.pack(side='left', fill='both', expand=True, padx=25, pady=25)

lb3 = ScrolledListbox(root)
lb3.pack(side='left', fill='both', expand=True, padx=25, pady=25)

# - add some values to listbox for scrolling -

for i in range(50):
    lb1.listbox.insert('end', str(i))
    lb2.listbox.insert('end', str(i+100))
    lb3.listbox.insert('end', str(i+200))

# - start -

root.mainloop()
```

[image]

Comment: Hi thanks a lot for the answer, i tried and it works but it doesn't work when i try to implement with my code, if you check my answer i implemented my code, and i notice that it works only if i delete the "sfondo" variable that simply contains and image that i use like a backgroud for my program

Comment: How to let it work with both my label and the frame ?? I hope you understand me and thanks again

Comment: you have to create new `Frame`, and put `Listbox` and `Scrollbar` in this `Frame`. And if you use `.place()` to put other elements then use `.place()` to put this `Frame`

Comment: I tried your code with my images and code works without any problems. Did you run script in console/terminal to see error messages? Maybe problem is not with new Frame but maybe there is some other mistake in `sfondo`. Maybe you have to use `/full/path/to/image.png` because code may work in different folder then you expect and it may not find image in this folder.

Comment: I solved putting the "sfondo" variable and the 2 following lines right BEFORE i create the frame, because if i put the "sfondo" label after i create the frame, the image covers my listbox, could this may have sense?

Comment: your code works correctly on my computer (I uses Linux Mint) - I have no idea what can make problem.

Comment: frankly, I would create `Frame` directly before `Listbox` to have all in one place - to make code more readable.

Comment: Now i have one other big problem :S ... i can't change the dimension and position of the listbox, if i add "lista_spese = Listbox(frame, width = 200, height=100)" i can add any value to width and height but the size of the listbox is the same, how to change?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244376/discussion-between-stefano9669-and-furas).

Comment: do you use `.place()` to put `Frame`? `.grid()` and `.pack()` automatically calculate size and this can make problem. And `padx`, pady` in `pack()` can decide where it will display. You may also need to set size for `Frame`. Different layout managers (`place()`, `grid()`, `pack()`) works in different way and they may need different settings.

Comment: You have `lista_spese.configure(.. , width=21, height=9, )` and this changes `width` and `height` - so you have to remove it  to get `Listbox(frame, width = 200, height=100)`.But `listbox` can get size in `number of chars and rows` instead of `pixels`

Comment: Mh it's a bit difficult, one last question is it possible to edit you answers using only ".place" instead of ".pack" ?

Comment: shortly: try to use it to see if it will work. But frankly I don't like `.place` because it needs too many calculations - it would need also to calculate size for Frame, etc. (with .pack()` or .grid()` it will calculate size of Frame automatically). And it doesn't look good when I want to resize window.